# Bootstrap - two/three inputs in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to write two or three inputs with bootstrap:
It should looks like:

```
label
input input input

label
input(30%) input(40%) input (30%)
```

Here's my code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><strong>test:</strong></label>
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 30%"/>
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 40%"/>
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 30%"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue? Do you have a question?

Comment: I've written that I'm looking for a help to organize this form just like I wrote.

Comment: don't get me wrong but I'm still unsure of what your issue is. I think it is clear what you want. It's not that clear what have you tried and why didn't that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use rows, they can be inserted almost everywhere.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```